# selecting rows with min and max values in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

my df:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['Adam','Adam','Adam','Adam'],'B':[24,90,67,12]})
```

I want to select only rows with same name with min and max value in this df.
i can do that using this code:

```
df_max=df[df['B']==(df.groupby(['A'])['B'].transform(max))]
df_min=df[df['B']==(df.groupby(['A'])['B'].transform(min))]
df=pd.concat([df_max,df_min])
```

Is there any way to do this in one line? i prefer to not create two additional df's and concat them at the end .

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) and [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) with reshape by [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and select rows by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df1 = df.loc[df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(['idxmax','idxmin']).melt()['value']].drop_duplicates()
```

Or [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df2 = df.loc[df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(['idxmax','idxmin']).stack()].drop_duplicates()
print (df2)
      A   B
1  Adam  90
3  Adam  12
```

Comment: one comment, i would add at the end .drop_duplicates(inplace=False) at the end of your lines because when there is only one record for specific name, your code is creating two values ( one for min , second for max)

Comment: @sygneto - Thank you for commnet, answer was edited.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `groupby`, `apply` and `loc` to select only the `min` or `max` value of column `'B'`.

```
ddf = df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x : x.loc[(x['B'] == x['B'].min()) | (x['B'] == x['B'].max())]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

The result is:

```
      A   B
0  Adam  90
1  Adam  12
```